# Why C# BackgroundWorker freeze MainForm/Thread

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I used example calculating Fibonacci, and it works fine.
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-5.0
But if I change Fibonacci calculating for loop the main Window freeze during "doWOrk".
The same situation is when from code below I remove `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);`
So, Why ? since "doWork" method work in background thread?
(This happens when progress is reported)

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var instance = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
        {
            int ik = (int)(i / (float)500000 * 100);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            instance.ReportProgress(ik);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

Comment: Because the progress reporting method (backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged in this case) runs on the thread that created the background worker. This is by design.

Comment: So I wonder what was the designer assumption...
Thanks

Comment: Probably that this would typically be created from a UI thread and that progress would be reported in the UI. UI elements can only be updated from the UI thread. You can dispatch calls on the UI thread manually from elsewhere by calling invoke, but this frees the background worker from having to do that explicitly when reporting progress.

Comment: ok, but.. 
If you use delegate and InvokeRequired for progress reporting "for loop" does not freez Main Form. If you use backgroundWorker it does ..